# Store database information in multidimensional associative array via foreach loop php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Howdie do,

I have an array of devices that are returned from a database. Each device has a hostname and if that hostname is open, it checks the model and description of the device. Should it match a preset list of devices, it needs to increment the counter and store the $desc, $model and counter in a multidimensional array.

I've never setup a multidimensional array before on the fly like this, so any help is appreciated

My code is below:

```
$servers = array();
foreach($devices as $device)
{
    $model = $device['model'];
    $host = $device['hostname'];
    $desc = $device['description'];
    $R410Model;
    $R410Desc;
    if($host == 'OPEN')
    {
        if (($model == 'DELL R410') && ($desc == "Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz"))
        {
            $R410HexCoreE5650Count++;
            $R410Model = $model;
            $R410Desc = $desc;
        }
     }
}

$servers[] = array('Dell R410 Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz' => array('Model' =>$R410Model, 'Description' =>$R410Desc,'Counter' => $R410HexCoreE5650Count));
```

However, once I go to print the counter from the sub-array, I'm not seeing any data returned:

```
print "<table class='table table-condensed table-hover'>";
print "<tr>";
print       "<td class='title'>Number of Open R410s Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz</td>";
foreach ($servers as $server)
{
    print "<td>"; 
    print $server['Dell R410 Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz']['Counter']; 
    print "</td>";
}
print   "</tr>";
print "</table>";
```

Edit: Based off the comments, I've updated the code and it's now displaying data. However, it's displaying every number leading up to the final count instead of just the final count.

Edit: I've fixed the duplicated counts and the count up. Updated code with the fix. Just move the array statement outside the foreach loop. Also, created temporary variables to store the model and desc which I then pass to the creation of my multidimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way you're building it, you have to reference it like this:

```
$server['Dell R410 Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz']['Counter'];
```

but you should ask why you are adding the big long 'Dell...' key to every entry ?

after you build you're array, do this:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($servers,true)."</pre>";
```

then you'll see how you are really building your array.

(edit: or dump it as json and take a look, but either way you probably can build the array simpler..)

Comment: The reason the Dell key is because I have multiple servers that I need to keep track of. E.g. I5, I7, Q9550

Comment: Thank you for explaining the way I was accessing was incorrect. The issue now is that it displays every number leading up to the final count. How do I get it to only display the final count?

Comment: you need to model/map your data and see how you need to manage/display and update it

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement is missing 
    `<td> </td>`  tags.

```
print "<table class='table table-condensed table-hover'>";
print "<tr>";
print "<td class='title'>Number of Open R410s Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz ";
foreach ($servers as $server)
{
 print $server['Counter'];
}
echo "</td>";
print   "</tr>";
print "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed the <td></td>